# Does OData v2 support POST of a contained entity?

Tags: odata, olingo

The OData v4 [Advanced Tutorial](http://www.odata.org/getting-started/advanced-tutorial/#createContain) provides an example of creating a Contained Entity.

> Create a Contained Entity
>   The request below creates a Trip for Person
>   with UserName 'russellwhyte'. Trips is a contained navigation property
>   for Person.
>
> POST serviceRoot/People('russellwhyte')/Trips

I'm trying to determine if v2 supported this concept of creating a Contained Entity.  The v4 [What's New](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/new-in-odata/v4.01/cn02/new-in-odata-v4.01-cn02.html) docs don't mention Contained Entity as something new.

However, I haven't found mention of this concept in any v2 docs.  Perhaps it was added in v3?

If by chance the concept of creating a contained entity existed in Odata v2, does Olingo v2 support it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is no.

Navigations was something that was extensively updated in OData 4. They were always bidirectional in OData 2 and were called Associations.

The reason you didn't find any information is because you were reading [What's new in OData 4.01](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/new-in-odata/v4.01/cn02/new-in-odata-v4.01-cn02.html) rather than [What's new in OData 4.0](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/new-in-odata/v4.0/cn01/new-in-odata-v4.0-cn01.html#_Toc366145510).

Though if you want to create entities by sending a POST request on a navigation property, you can do that in OData 2 as well as in Olingo 2.

The catch here is that, as the associations are always bi-directional, you need a corresponding `AssociationSet` for the navigation property, which will require a corresponding `EntitySet`.So the entity, created by sending a POST request on the navigating property will not really be an embedded one, and will have a top level URL too.